# What access modifier to use

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a base class:

```
public class A {
    public float someValue;

    <Access Modifier Here> float SomeValue {
        get {
            return someValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to derive from it:

```
public class B : A {
    public float SomeProperty {
        get {
            return SomeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

What access modifier would I use if I want to make the *SomeValue* property only available to the deriving class and not anywhere else?

Comment: `protected` is what you are looking for.

Comment: protected for only derived classes

Comment: [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).  Sounds like `protected` is what you are looking for.

Comment: well @nopeflow beat me to it.

Comment: I like that people are voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: You'll find a good explanation on Programmers: [Why do we need private variables?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for only derived classes.. use `protected`

Protected means that access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.

Comment: It works, thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: @Tayab please mark answer as accepted so it shows that your issue has been resolved.